# Deleting local copy in subversion 1.7.5

Tags: svn

How do I delete a local working copy that I checked out in error? I have a directory containing different checked out trees (and a .svn directory) and just want to delete one of them. Just deleting the files doesn't work - any update to the parent or attempt to re-use the tree name repopulates the files. svn delete doesn't work either, I can't commit from the parent, or still re-use the tree name. [Yes I could ignore the "deleted" tree but I want to re-use the name.]

There is an option keep_local on svn delete which keeps the local copy of files but removes them from the repository. I basically want to do the opposite - remove the local copy *as if it had never existed* - but don't touch the repository. Is there a way of doing this please?

Comment: what does ``svn delete`` say?

Comment: Oh it works fine and deletes all the files locally. Then I try to re-use the project name for a new checkout and it puts them all back. And after doing a svn delete I can't do a commit or I would delete the repository files.

Comment: Is it just a check out or is it bound to the upper directory by means of `svn:externals`?

Comment: Just as further clarification, part of the problem is multiple checkouts into the same parent directory. This means they share the same .svn directory so I can't just delete the tree and its .svn folder in entirety.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution lies with [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

Let's say you have a directory named `parent` (i.e. the root of your checkout) with directories named `child01`, `child02`, and `child03` - and `child02` contains directories and files which you don't need in your checkout. You'd tell Subversion that `child02` should be seen as "sparse" with:

```
> cd parent\child02
> svn update --set-depth empty
```

From then on when ever you issue `svn update` on the `parent` folder, Subversion will "ignore" any updates for the `child02` folder.

Of course, this is checkout-specific. If you `svn checkout` another copy of `parent`, then `child02` will contain its files and folders, because the default depth for `svn checkout` (and in fact all commands) is `infinity`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ingenious! However not really what I want. I want to remove all trace of the local copy as if it had never been created.

Comment: Well, AFAIK the only other way would be to edit the checkout metadata and remove all references to the folder and its subfolders and files. I must warn you though, that this is playing with fire so be very cautious. Also, again this would only affect your current checkout.

Comment: Yes you're right this would theoretically work, but unfortunately thousands of files are involved and the metadata is apparently distributed over a huge number of files. I'm not confident I could even edit the metadata correctly.

Comment: So, sparse directories best fits your scenario - except that the folder in question will remain in the checkout, empty and Forever Alone :)